# Unity 2019.3 HDRI SkyBox

Tags: unity, skybox, hdr

I am trying to create an HDRI SkyBox out of 6 textures but after I create the cubemap with Assets → Legacy → Cubemap and drag it in the HDRI Sky I get an all white environment. Is this a problem with the textures or maybe I am missing some setting?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The legacy cubemap pipeline of dragging six separate textures into a cubemap asset in Unity does not support HDR.

To get HDR (and better filtering as a bonus), you need to import your cubemap as a single image, not as six separate images.

[As described in the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Cubemap.html), you need to lay out your 6 views into one image file with one of these arrangements:

[image: Supported cubemap layouts]

(I've omitted the Equirectangular/LatLong and SphereMap options since they'd require re-projecting your images instead of just pasting them side-by-side).

You can use any image editing software you like to do this arrangement.

Place the resulting single image into your Assets folder, and in its import settings, choose Texture Type: Default, Shape: Cube.

The result will be a Cubemap asset that you can use as your sky.